# How can I use collections as a Source in Akka Streams?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am new to using the Akka Streams API.  I am attempting to create custom graph stages.  For each of my stages I would like each "element" to be a scala collection, for example, a vector of integers.  However, when I use Source (Vector(1,2,3)) or something along those lines it passes the elements 1, 2, 3 individually.  Is there a way I can pass in the entire vector, as the results of the stage depend on the relationships between the items within the vector?  Currently I am using a List as a "wrapper" but I do not like that solution.  Thanks in advance.

Example code:

```scala
val graphStage: Graph[FlowShape[Vector[Int], Vector[Int]], NotUsed = new GraphStage

val vector = Source(Vector(1,2,3))  //passes in 1, 2, 3 individually, want Vector(1,2,3) passed in whole

val resultFuture = vector.via(graphStage).runForeach( _ => println)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Source.single`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.3/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#single[T](element:T):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed]):

```
val vector = Source.single(Vector(1, 2, 3))
```